# How to disable preflight request to MarkLogic server from C# WebApi

Tags: c#, marklogic, http-status-code-401, webapi, preflight

Tech stack as follows

- .Net core WebApi (C#)
- MarkLogic 9.0.8.2

We have developed MarkLogic API with basic authentication and while calling it from C# WebApi, we are passing credentials in header.

We noticed that MarkLogic access logs is having 2 entries i.e.

- xx.xxx.xxx.xx - - [18/May/2020:06:05:35 +0000] "GET /getcontent?query=test&offset=1&size=10&format=Extended&sortOrder=ASC&transform=&IncludeFacet=true **HTTP/1.1" 401 209** - -
- xx.xxx.xxx.xx - **MLUser** [18/May/2020:06:05:35 +0000] "GET /getcontent?query=test&offset=1&size=10&format=Extended&sortOrder=ASC&transform=&IncludeFacet=true **HTTP/1.1" 200** 44229 - -

Same request goes with 401 i.e. Unauthorized and then immediately with 200 i.e. successful.

We realized that calling API endpoint from C# WebAPI is a doing preflight request with OPTIONS before calling actual request.

We found there is option to send content type as 'text/plain' to solve this issue, but we can't as we have JSON object and then we need to do more to parse text to JSON object.

When we are calling from PostMan, we are facing with the same problem.

Due to this, when we have loads of requests on API, ML API returns with 401 error on Firewall and then FW blocks all requests considering it as Brute Force Attack.

Is there any way, we can disable preflight request calling?

```
MarkLogicHttpClient _client;

var queryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "query", searchRequest.Query },
    { "offset", searchRequest.Offset.ToString() },
    { "size", searchRequest.Size.ToString() },
    { "format", searchRequest.Format },
    { "sortOrder", searchRequest.SortOrder.ToString().ToUpper() },
    { "transform", transform }
};

var searchUri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("getcontent", queryParams);

var response = await _client.GetAsync(searchUri);

//Startup.cs

services.AddHttpClient<IMarkLogicClient, MarkLogicHttpClient>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = MarkLogicEndpoint;
})
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    new HttpClientHandler
    {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential
        {
            UserName = UserName,
            Password = Password
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: How are you adding credentials to the header?  Can you provide the code?

Comment: Hello Brent, Thanks for your reply. I have added code in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HttpClient sends an Authorization header only after first receiving a 401 response with a WWW-Authenticate header from the server.

By default, HttpClient waits for the 401 response before authorizing on *every* request.

There are two ways to reduce the number of 401 responses.

**Set the `HttpClientHandler.PreAuthenticate` Property**

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMarkLogicClient, MarkLogicHttpClient>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = MarkLogicEndpoint;
})
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    new HttpClientHandler
    {
        // cache the WWW-Authenticate response and send Authorize header
        // on all subsequent requests
        PreAuthenticate = true,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential
        {
            UserName = UserName,
            Password = Password
        }
    });
```

**Or, manually add Authorize Header to `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders`**

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMarkLogicClient, MarkLogicHttpClient>(client =>
{
    // construct HTTP Basic Authorization header and send on every request
    // Do not add credentials to HttpClientHandler
    var authorization= "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Username + ":" + Password));
    client.BaseAddress = MarkLogicEndpoint;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authorization);
});
```

Comment: Hello Brent, Thanks for your reply with example. So when i implemented with PreAutheticate, still it was throwing 401 error for the 1st time and then all 200 requests, but then if no request in server for specific time (i saw if no request for 2 mins),  i again saw 401 error. with 2nd approach, we will never get 401 error ? I am asking because to test, i need to follow long process. I mean actually i want to disable preflight request.

Comment: With second approach you should expect no preflight and no 401

Comment: Hello Brent, Thanks, So you mean, it was httphandler which was causing preflight request ?

Comment: Yes, the way the HttpClient and HttpHandler implement the HTTP Basic Authentication results in sporadic authentication preflight requests, even with PreAuthenticate enabled.  Hard coding the Authorize header, as in the second example, never does an authentication preflight.

Comment: Thanks Brent for your reply. Now frequency of 401 is very low, but still i see 401 error in access log files and then same request with 200. I restarted the service also just to make sure it does not take anything from cache. And they were not at start of 1st requests, they were in between.Hard coding is also doing kind of caching? It seems like preflight request is still happening with 2nd approach as well, though 401 numbers are minimal.

Comment: 2nd approach solved the issue, Thanks Brent for your help.